# How to design my Geo-Distributed Postgres database cluster?

Tags: postgresql, cluster-computing, patroni

Our business have a PostgreSQL DB cluster running in China, managed by Patroni with 1 master node and 4 slave nodes. Now as business expanded to Europe, we are planning to setup another cluster there.

The question is how to manage/sync two master db node across continents to achieve the best performance. We have been investigate on this matter, currently trying Bucardo to sync two master, but don’t know if it is the right practice for the future scaling.